# Truncate Magento 1.9 Core URL Rewrites

Tags: sql, database, magento, url-rewriting, magento-1.9

I need to delete/truncate the Magento 1.9 core URL rewrites which are **older than 3 months of core_url_rewrite table** in database.

What's the exact SQL query to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

You can't. There is no information about the date in the `core_url_rewrite` table. You should also watch out for custom redirects, that won't be recreated automatically. The SQL request to clear out the table, without deleting custom redirects is :

```
DELETE FROM core_url_rewrite WHERE is_system = 1;
```

Once you run a reindex, all the categories and products URLs will be generated again.

Answer (score 0):

You can truncate whole table, Magento will automatically create required ones, just do a reindexing of catalog url rewrites.

Comment: No. Magento recreates only the system redirects by doing so, not the custom ones, this a very dangerous thing to do.